# How to get the Following URL Structure in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have a

- Custom Post Type - Awards (slug = awards)
- Custom Taxonomy - Award Giver (awards-giver) (e.g. Oscars, Golden Globe, etc)
- Custon Taxonomy - Awards Types (award-type) (e.g. Best Actor, Best Film, etc)
- Custom Taxonomy - Award Year (award-year)

Now I want to dynamically have pages on my site with the following URL Structure

**example.com/awards/oscars/year/2011**

**example.com/awards/oscars/best-actor/** (which will list all the winners of best actor award till now of all years)

I need to get these url structures working in WordPress. Any Advice?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: select the parent page in `oscars` ans best-actor as well

Comment: I don't have pages, these are custom post types!

Comment: where will post your content?

Comment: have you created custom template for above both urls? because rewrite url need to be set accordingly as we need to give actual working file url also in rewrite rule.

Comment: This should have been asked on the Wordpress Development site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for: example.com/awards/oscars/year/2011

This might help you. Put below code into your functions.php file:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^awards/([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)/year/([0-9]+)/?', 'your_actual_working_file_url.php?award_type_slug=$matches[0]&year=$matches[3]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');

RewriteRule ^awards/([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)/year/([0-9]+)/?$  your_actual_working_file_url.php?award_type_slug=$1&year=$2
```

Make sure you put your actual working file url/path in above code as per your custom template file name or default template file name.